# .Net Core 2 SPA/Angular Template - Render Global CSS

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am very new to Webpack and the [.NET Core 2 Angular SPA Template](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/). I'm trying to create a **global stylesheet** for the entire site. I could reference that style in the Layout view to render it in the main view, but then I lose the benefits of the pre-render engine and bundling with WebPack (as well as minification).

The Webpack documentation says that in order to include static CSS that you need to add a require(../filepath) to your module, but I don't see a way to do this in the boot.browser.ts.

I'm still just getting started with .NET core so my site is basically just the OOB .Net Core 2 template with Angular. I'm keeping my global styles sheet in ClientApp/Styles/Global.css at the moment. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This may help http://derpturkey.com/asp-net-core-bootstrap-customization/ Also checkout summary on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455421/asp-net-core-angular-spa-template-add-custom-bootstrap-theme-to-webpack-config-j/46688694#46688694

Comment: Consider using Angular CLI. Search for global styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in visual studio 2019 Angular template with ASP.Net Core 2.2 you don't have to manage webpack file like old version. I'm assume that you are using Angular 5 with webpack template.

Create ASP.Net Core app like this

[image]

Then you will see style.css in your angular app. That is where you put your global style

[image: enter code here]

Hope it will help you. Best regards.

Comment: How to reference the bundled css and js files by Cli in the razor view page (e,g home.cshtml) instead of default index.html

Comment: You can view source of the index.html when you run the angular app you will see the script include in the bottom of the index.html. Copy all of those line to your home.cshtml and you should be good

Comment: So during the production build (dotnet publish / ng build --prod) will these file names be same? my prod build will be placed in "ClientApp/dist".If I copy those scripts to Home.cshtml then will it work for production build also?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing that very thing. Apologies for the delayed reply.