# ASP.NET core angular SPA template add Custom bootstrap theme to webpack.config.js

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I need to add custom bootstrap template to asp.net core spa template.
I've created the temple using command:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
dotnet new angular
```

The generated template fits my needs although I need to use a custom bootrap theme which I placed in wwwroot folder.

```
CustomTheme
├── css
│   ├── style.less
├── js
├── fonts
├── img
```

Can someone please help me out explaining how to add this theme to webpack.config.vendor.js?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

How to enable less build is also well documented:

[Example: A simple Webpack setup that builds LESS](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#example-a-simple-webpack-setup-that-builds-less)

This post, by Brian Mancini, relating to the React SPA template may help or apply similarly to the Angular SPA Template as well:

[ASP.NET Core Bootstrap Customization](http://derpturkey.com/asp-net-core-bootstrap-customization/)

Copying a summary below:

1. Install LESS and less-loader

   ```
   npm install --save less less-loader
   ```
2. Under ClientApp setup the following files and folders

   ```
   less/site.less
   less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less
   less/bootstrap/variables.less
   ```
3. Configure the bootstrap and variables less files

   ```
   /* less/bootsrap/bootstrap.less */
   /* import bootstrap from source */
   @import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';

   /* import custom overrides */
   @import 'variables.less';



   /* less/bootstrap/variables.less */

   /* import the original file */
   @import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/variables.less';


   /* Variables your overrides below
   -------------------------------------------------- */




   /* less/site.less */
   @import './bootstrap/variables.less';
   /* your overrides below */
   ```
4. Modify `webpack.config.vendor.js`

   Remove configuration related to css file generation. Final vendor config will look like below:

   See gist [webpack.vendor.config.js](https://gist.github.com/stormwild/b4db06b1f18f8ccb12e22643a549f308#file-webpack-vendor-config-js)
5. Modify `webpack.config.js` to perform the less conversion

   See gist [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/stormwild/b4db06b1f18f8ccb12e22643a549f308#file-webpack-config-js)
6. Modify `boot-client.ts` to include site and bootstrap less

   ```
   import './less/site.less';  
   import './less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
   ```
7. Test your build by running

   ```
   node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js  
   node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js
   ```
8. Modify `_Layout.cshtml` to include `bootstrap.css`